# How does Leetcode OJ make judgement?

Tags: c++

I'm now resolving the #5 problem of Leetcode OJ, [ZigZag Conversion](https://leetcode.com/problems/zigzag-conversion/). The codes below is my answer:

```
class Solution {
public:
    string convert(string s, int nRows) {
        int n = (int)s.size(), block_size = (nRows - 1);
        if (n <= nRows || nRows == 1)
            return s;

        string re = "";

        int len = nRows - 2 + nRows;

        for (int left = len, right = 0, i = 0; i < nRows; ++i) {
            bool is_left = false;
            char current = 0;
            int offset = 0;

            while (i + offset <= n) {
                if (!is_left) {
                    if (left != 0) {
                        current = s[i + offset];
                        re.push_back(current);
                    }
                    offset += left;
                    is_left = true;
                } else {
                    if (right != 0) {
                        current = s[i + offset];
                        re.push_back(current);
                    }
                    offset += right;
                    is_left = false;
                }
            }
            left -= 2;
            right = len - left;
        }
        return re;
    }
 };
```

After my submission, the OJ replied: *Submission Result: Wrong Answer*. However, it also said that my codes' output is "ACB" and the expected answer is exactly same of "ACB".

Why the answer is wrong when the output and expected is same.
By the way, What's the compiler version of c++ of Leetcode? Sometime, the output of my g++ compiler is different from the leetcode's output.

Comment: How can anyone here at SO know? Have you looked for a FAQ? Leetcode forums?

Comment: You're right, Leetcode forum is a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

From Leetcode forum:

```
Language    Version Notes
C++          g++ 6.3
```

Comment: please more clarify your answer